# Updating a record in model based on another record

Tags: elm

I have something like this:

```
type alias Record = 
    { id : String
    , nextId : String
    , value : String
    , result : Int
    }

type alias Model = List Record
model = [
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
]

...

update id model =
    List.map (updateRecord id) model

updateRecord id record =
    if record.id == id then
        {record | result = 1}
    else
        record
```

Basically what I need when I call `update` with some `id` is to update record with that `id` (that part I already have) but also grab the value from the record's `nextId`, find another record with `record.id == nextId` and pass the `value` from the first record to the second one

Basically what I am looking for written in JS:

```
function update(id, model) {
    var nextId, value;
    var newModel1 = model.map(function(record) {
        if (record.id === id) {
            record.result = 1;
            nextId = record.nextId;
            value = record.value;
            return record;
        } else {
            return record;
        }
    });

    var newModel2 = model.map(function(record) {
        if (record.id === nextId) {
            record.value = value;
            return record;
        } else {
            return record;
        }
    });

    return newModel2;
}
```

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to give you what you're looking for:

```elm
type alias UpdateNext = 
  { nextId : String
  , value : String
  }

update id model =
  let
    (matchedModel, nextToUpdate) = match id model
  in
    case nextToUpdate of
      Nothing ->
        model
      Just next ->
        updateNext next matchedModel

match : String -> Model -> (Model, Maybe UpdateNext)
match id model =
  case model of
    [] ->
      ([], Nothing)
    (x::xs) ->
      if x.id == id then
        ( { x | result = 1 } :: xs
        , Just { nextId = x.nextId, value = x.value }
        )
      else
        let (ys, updateNext) = match id xs
        in (x :: ys, updateNext)

updateNext : UpdateNext -> Model -> Model
updateNext next model =
  case model of
    [] ->
      []
    (x::xs) ->
      if x.id == next.nextId then
        { x | value = next.value } :: xs
      else
        x :: updateNext next xs
```

This is going to be more efficient than `List.map` because it short-circuits processing when it has matched the result.